# How can I validate file type and file size using Joi?

Tags: nestjs, joi

I am using FileInterceptor to upload file in nestjs application and I want to validate file with Joi. This is what I have tried.

```html
Joi.object({
  filename: Joi.string(),
  headers: Joi.object({
    'content-type': Joi.string().valid('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif')
  }),
  _data: Joi.binary().max(100).encoding("base64")
})
```